# How to find the current path in the business process?

Tags: mysql, sql, bpmn, business-logic, business-rules

**Purpose of the application:**

I am working on a Saas application for property management.
Using BPMN 2.0 artefacts to modeliez business rules.

**Pilote BPMN process: Tenant departure management**

My pilote is the [following process modelization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq9Tb.png)

**Purpose of this question**
To make it easier to understand by the user, user ask to see a timeline rather than a BPMN process.

The timeline is base on a MySQL request that should provide the "current user pathway".

> Show me all the tasks I have to do until the end of the process or
>   the next "not yet answered" gateway?

Pathway rules are:

rule 1: From start event (position = 1) show all artefacts until you find a gateway where the result is NULL (the user did not answer yet).

rule 2: When you meet a gateway wherethere is an answer - field result is set - , **keep going on the selected branch.**

> The problem I am facing is about the selected branch (see below).

**MySQL schemas**

I chose to implement the model through 3 tables:

1. activities hasMany artefacts - this table is not set for this question for we are focused on only one activity.
2. artefacts hasOne parent, hasOne child (to itself) trough artefacts_realtionships
3. artefacts_relationships : join table to describe the 'pathways' of the process. Please note that this cannot be a tree for "leaves may join at the end".

*artefacts table*

```
    CREATE TABLE `artefacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `activity_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `options` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `alert_message` text,
  `alert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

*artefacts_relationships table*

```
CREATE TABLE `artefacts_relationships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `child_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `choice` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**MySQL implementation for the pilote process**

You will find a [running MySQL fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38c65f26e17f2f7d72c80be0ef01e783)

Here is the artefacts_relationships table values
[artefacts_relationships table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lkj6.png)

**The 'gateway' artefact functionality**

A '**gateway**' is a **question**.
Here it is a 'yes/no' question that with either to the 'yes' - choice = 1 - or the 'no' - choice = 2 - branch of the process.

The answer given by the user is store in the field "result" at the row of the gateway artefact.

The **orientation switch** to branches is given through the **field "choice"** in the artefacts_relationships_table, at the row where the parent_id is the gateway artefacts.id.

Here I show the case of the artefacts table when the user answer "no" to the question: choice = 2
[artefacts table values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecNE5.png)

My query, so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    currents.type AS current_type,
    currents.options AS current_options,
    currents.name AS current_name,
    currents.result AS current_result,
    currents.position AS current_position,
    CASE
        -- Traitement de la gateway
        WHEN currents.type = 'gateway'
            AND currents.result IS NULL
        THEN 'stop1'
        WHEN 
            parents.type = 'gateway'
            AND (
                parents.result != parent_relationships.choice
                OR parents.result IS NULL)
        THEN 'stop2'
        WHEN 
            parents.type != 'gateway'
            OR parents.type IS NULL
        THEN currents.position 

        ELSE NULL
    END AS filtered_position,
FROM artefacts AS currents
-- relation parent_current
LEFT JOIN artefacts_relationships AS parent_relationships
ON currents.id = parent_relationships.child_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM artefacts AS parents
    -- WHERE xxx
    )
    AS parents
ON parent_relationships.parent_id = parents.id

  -- relation current_enfant
LEFT JOIN artefacts_relationships AS child_relationships
ON currents.id = child_relationships.parent_id

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM artefacts 
        -- WHERE xxx
    )
    AS children
ON child_relationships.child_id = children.id
WHERE 
    currents.activity_id = 1
    AND currents.position <= IFNULL(
                        (SELECT position FROM artefacts
                        WHERE type = 'gateway'
                            AND result IS NULL
                        ORDER BY position
                        LIMIT 1), 9999)
    AND (parents.type != 'gateway'
        OR(parents.type = 'gateway' AND parents.result = parent_relationships.choice)
        )
ORDER BY current_position
;
```

We should focus only on the 'current' row

```
**The problem:** 
current_position 7 and 8 from the 'yes' branch (choice = 1) should be filtered (removed) since current_position 6 is not selected.
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: You might want to ready up on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because this is a very extensive question with way too much information. We souldn't have to learn about your whole project to be able to help you with your question.

Comment: Thanx for your answer @JoakimDanielson : I do realize that was too much demanding.
I think about making the all question differently, and if not, I will remove this question.